# Execute javascript once Record view is fully loaded in SugarCrm 7.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, sugarcrm

You can add JS events in SugarCRM 7.2 by creating a custom record.js.

The problem I'm having is that they fire before the page is loaded so elements I'm trying to affect don't exist.

I have tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() { alert(0); }) // fires before page is loaded
$(document).on('load', function() { alert(1); }) // doesn't fire at all
$(window).load(function() { alert(2); }) // doesn't fire at all
```

Any help in resolving this would be much appreciated.

record.js

```
({
extendsFrom: 'RecordView',

initialize: function (options) {
    this._super('initialize', [options]);

   SUGAR.util.ajaxCallInProgress = function () {
        alert(0);
         $('[name="duplicate_button"]').hide(); 
},


})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I got this to work was to use the following code in custom/modules//clients/base/views/record/record.js

```
({
extendsFrom: 'AccountsRecordView',
initialize: function (options) {
    this._super('initialize', [options]);

    this.on("render", this.SetHomeButtons, this); //calls SetHomeButtons

},

SetHomeButtons: function () {
 some code ....

},
})
```

The function SetHomeButtons is called once the page is loaded

Another way of doing it is to overwrite the render function to call your custom code

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't work because of AJAX.

Edit: in Sugar 7 you have the function SUGAR.util.ajaxCallInProgress()  it retruns false when every Request is done (all Content Elements have been loaded)

Comment: your suggestion is for Sugar 6.5 not Sugar 7 - in Sugar 6.5 I have no problems adding JavaScript - Sugar 7.2 is very very different

Comment: Sorry I changed my answer for Sugar 7

Comment: looked promising but doesnt fire :( - I have edited my question to show the code I'm testing

Comment: SUGAR.util.ajaxCallInProgress() just retruns true or false. You have to check it to know when the dom is loaded and you can run your function. :                                                    `function loaded(){
  if (SUGAR.util.ajaxCallInProgress()){
    setTimeout(loaded,100);
  } else {
    //DO something
  }
}`

Comment: I'm afraid this gets called before page is fully loaded - beginning to think I'll have to try a diffent method

Comment: Hello @mjsolo I am getting the same issue.Have you find the solution?